# Office 365 migration - testing

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

Our client is moving from sharePoint 2003 to SharePoint Online.

I am a functional tester. What are the testing needs to do from the manual testing perspective for this migration activities?

Can someone give inputs on this - what needs to be tested as part of SharePoint Online and also as part of migration etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare an inventory list of existing sharepoint environment. Do a thorough check on source SharePoint setup. I am listing down certain SharePoint components for your considerations:

1. Server Farm
2. Document Workspace
3. Custom solution
4. custom Workflows
5. Custom Permission Levels
6. User alerts
7. Retention policy
8. Blocked File types
9. Branding/UI Customizations / Site theme
10. Email enabled Lists
11. Infopath Forms
12. Custom web parts
13. Top Link Navigation
14. Quick Launch
15. Information rights management-IRM
16. Taxonomy and Term Sets

Answer (score 0):

You need to concentrate on following

1. Find the customization made on 2003
2. Find workflow's used
3. Collect various data stored in the site.
4. Business processes that are automated in 2003

Once you have this information you can test those in particular.

Basically you can avoid testing SharePoint features like adding list items etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 customers are responsible for the content validation and functional testing. As you are moving from 2003 to SharePoint online(2013), which required to good test plan. So you should check the following things.

- Custom code that needs to be ported,Custom list templates, Custom site templates, Custom web parts
- Third-party web parts
- Feature mapping, including deprecated features, such as SPS portal
  listings
- Lookups, connections to external data source.
- Make sure content migrated successfully and properly In placed.
- check the workflows, test them, Make sure alerts properly works.
- Check the links, url redirection etc.
- Also you should test the new funcationality as well.